# Embedded documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have two models:

```
class MenuPosition
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :category, type: String

  field :portion, type: Integer
  field :carbo, type: Float
  field :fat, type: Float
  field :protein, type: Float

  field :colesterol, type: Float
  field :saturated_fats, type: Float
  field :suger, type: Float

  field :omega3, type: Float
  field :omega6, type: Float

  index :name, unique: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

and

```
class Menu
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :assigned_date, type: Date
  embeds_many :menu_position

  index :assigned_date, unique: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :assigned_date

  def self.test
    position = {
      "name" => "pork",
      "category" => "meal",
      "portion" => 100,
      "carbo" => 4,
      "fat" => 2,
      "protein" => 5,
      "colesterol" => 1,
      "saturated_fats" => 1
    }

    MenuPosition.safely.create!(position)
    position = MenuPosition.find_by_name("pork")
    p position

    Menu.safely.create!(assigned_date: Date.new(2011, 04, 01))
    menu = Menu.where(assigned_date: Date.new(2011, 04, 01)).entries[0]
    p menu

    menu.menu_position = [position]
    menu.save

    menu = Menu.where(assigned_date: Date.new(2011, 04, 01)).entries[0]
    p menu
    p menu.menu_position

    return 0
  end
```

I use self.test method to test embedded documents:

```
it "test it" do
  Menu.test.should eq(0)
end
```

When I run the test I have MenuPosition and Menu inserted, but Menu.MenuPosition is not filled:

```
#<MenuPosition _id: 4f87f93e83b7e01e4800003e, _type: nil, name: "pork", category: "meal", portion: 100, carbo: 4.0, fat: 2.0, protein: 5.0, colesterol: 1.0, saturated_fats: 1.0, suger: nil, omega3: nil, omega6: nil>
#<Menu _id: 4f87f93e83b7e01e4800003f, _type: nil, assigned_date: 2011-04-01 00:00:00 UTC>
#<Menu _id: 4f87f93e83b7e01e4800003f, _type: nil, assigned_date: 2011-04-01 00:00:00 UTC>
[] // <- here is menu.menu_position
```

How can I fix it?

**Update:**

I have tried this:

```
Menu.create(assigned_date: Date.new(2011, 04, 01))
menu = Menu.where(assigned_date: Date.new(2011, 04, 01)).entries[0]
menu.menu_position.create(position)
menu.save
menu = Menu.where(assigned_date: Date.new(2011, 04, 01)).entries[0]
p menu
p menu.menu_position
```

But it return:

```
<Menu _id: 4f880f0a83b7e0194c00003e, _type: nil, assigned_date: 2011-04-01 00:00:00 UTC>
[]
```

**Updated 2:**

It works if I add `embedded_in :menu` into MenuPosition.  But in this case I cannot store MenuPosition documents in MongoDb without Menu document :(

Comment: I suspect that it is because you save the menu_position before setting the menu on it - which makes it a document in its own right (ie. in it's own, separate collection), rather than an embedded document in menu. Have you tried creating but not saving the menu position, setting it on the menu then saving the menu itself?

Comment: How can I create MenuPosition, but not save it ?

Comment: Use `new` instead of `create`?

Comment: Or create the menu first, then use `create` to create the menu_position setting the menu on it at the point of creation?

Comment: Hmmm, sorry I can't be of more help. If I think of anything I'll let you know!

Comment: Ah, just seen your second update. Yes - I think they have to be one or the other.